# Why Can't I set a Class object's "Active" attr to false using the QBO API v3

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

I'm trying to full-update this QuickBooks Online v3 API object, setting the active attribute to false (i.e. 'soft deleting' it). It's not working.

The documentation for this feature is [here](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/api/accounting):

Here's the request json blob:

```
{
    "FullyQualifiedName": "Tickets", 
    "domain": "QBO", 
    "Name": "Tickets", 
    "SyncToken": "0", 
    "SubClass": false, 
    "sparse": false, 
    "Active": false, 
    "Id": "100000000000221202", 
}
```

And the response:

```
{
  "Class": {
    "Name": "Tickets",
    "SubClass": false,
    "FullyQualifiedName": "Tickets",
    "Active": true,
    "domain": "QBO",
    "sparse": false,
    "Id": "100000000000221202",
    "SyncToken": "0",
    "MetaData": {
      "CreateTime": "2013-05-15T13:23:15-07:00",
      "LastUpdatedTime": "2013-05-15T13:23:15-07:00"
    }
  },
  "time": "2014-12-07T08:06:38.543-08:00"
}
```

Why is it still active?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it's on the [list of known issues](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0100_accounting/0600_more/qbo_v3_known_issues).